# R aggregate gives differently structured results using subsets from the same data

Tags: r, aggregate, boxplot, summary

I'm making diurnal cycles of windspeed based on a dataframe (ball) of several year's hourly data. I want to plot them by season, so I subset out the dates I need and join them like this:

```
b8 = subset(ball, as.Date(date)>="2008-09-01 00:00:00, GMT" & as.Date(date)<= "2008-11-30 23:00:00, GMT"  )
b9  = subset(ball, as.Date(date)>="2009-09-01 00:00:00, GMT" & as.Date(date)<= "2009-11-30 23:00:00, GMT"  )
b10 = subset(ball,  as.Date(date)>="2010-09-01 00:00:00, GMT" & as.Date(date)<= "2010-11-30 23:00:00, GMT")
ballspr = rbind(b8,b9,b10)
```

I then get a diurnal cycle using this:

```
sprwsdiurnal <- aggregate(ballspr["ws"], format(ballspr["date"],"%H"),summary, na.rm=T)
```

For three out of four seasons this make an object with this structure:

```
   date                                               ws
1    00  0.200, 1.000, 1.600, 2.021, 2.500, 8.000, 5.000
2    01  0.100, 1.000, 1.600, 1.988, 2.500, 8.600, 1.000
3    02  0.100, 1.000, 1.700, 1.982, 2.600, 8.900, 1.000
```

...through to 24 hours...

```
23   22  0.100, 1.200, 1.800, 2.222, 2.950, 9.100, 1.000
24   23  0.100, 1.000, 1.600, 2.072, 2.700, 8.800, 1.000
```

This is what I want as boxplot will work with this:

```
par(  mar = c(5, 5, 2, 2))
boxplot(sprwsdiurnal$ws, col="dodger blue",pch=16,font.lab=2,cex.lab=1.5,cex.axis=2,xlab="Hour",range=0, ylab=quote(Windspeed ~ "(" * m ~ s ^-1 * ")"),xaxt="n",main="Spring")
axis(1, at=seq(1,24, by=1),labels=seq(1,24, by=1),cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5, font.lab=2)
```

The trouble is one season comes out like this:

```
      date ws.Min. ws.1st Qu. ws.Median ws.Mean ws.3rd Qu. ws.Max. ws.NA's
1    00   0.000      1.300     2.100   2.539      3.200  10.500   2.000
2    01   0.100      1.275     2.100   2.499      3.200   9.800   2.000
3    02   0.200      1.200     2.000   2.514      3.400   9.000   2.000
```

...through to 24 hours...

```
23   22   0.100      1.200     1.950   2.582      3.325  11.900   2.000
24   23   0.100      1.300     2.000   2.585      3.400  11.200   2.000
```

Boxplot does not work with this format. I can't explain why this happens, when all the code for each season is the same and they are being subsetted from the same dataframe. Why does one come out differently? Any ideas appreciated.

EDIT:Here's the data. I've checked these two seasons and they still give the two different formats shown above.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5kss0bgjyhrtw1/ball.csv

```
ball=read.csv("ball.csv", header=T)
ball$date = as.POSIXct(strptime(ball$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "GMT"))

win9  = subset(ball, as.Date(date)>="2009-06-01 00:00:00, GMT" & as.Date(date)<= "2009-08-31 23:00:00, GMT"  )
aut9  = subset(ball, as.Date(date)>="2009-03-01 00:00:00, GMT" & as.Date(date)<= "2009-05-31 23:00:00, GMT"  )
spr9  = subset(ball, as.Date(date)>="2009-09-01 00:00:00, GMT" & as.Date(date)<= "2009-11-30 23:00:00, GMT"  )
sum9  = subset(ball, as.Date(date)>="2008-12-01 00:00:00, GMT" & as.Date(date)<= "2009-02-28 23:00:00, GMT"  )


sprdiurnal <- aggregate(spr9["ws"], format(spr9["date"],"%H"),summary, na.rm=T)
par(  mar = c(5, 5, 4, 2))
 boxplot(sprdiurnal$ws, col=colours()[109],pch=16,cex.lab=1.5,cex.axis=1.5,xlab="Hour",range=0, ylab=quote(Wind ~ speed ~ "(" * m * "s" ^-1 * ")"),xaxt="n",main="")
axis(1, at=seq(1,24, by=1),labels=seq(1,24, by=1),cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5) 

windiurnal <- aggregate(win9["ws"], format(win9["date"],"%H"),summary, na.rm=T)
par(  mar = c(5, 5, 4, 2))
boxplot(windiurnal$ws, col=colours()[109],pch=16,cex.lab=1.5,cex.axis=1.5,xlab="Hour",range=0, ylab=quote(Wind ~ speed ~ "(" * m * "s" ^-1 * ")"),xaxt="n",main="")
axis(1, at=seq(1,24, by=1),labels=seq(1,24, by=1),cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5)
```

Comment: I'd be happy to try to help, but without a reproducible example, I can't really do much.

Comment: @Elizabeth, how did the answer I've shared below work out for you? If there are still problems, do let me know! Thanks.

Comment: apologies for the belated reply. Thank you - it worked perfectly and you explained it so well I even understand why! +1 and more if I could

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "problem", so far as I can tell, is that the result of `summary` in your `aggregate` function for "`sprdiurnal`" results in a rectangular dataset that R stores as a `matrix`, while for your other subsets, since some hours include `NA` and others don't the dataset is not rectangular, so R stores the summary as a `list`.

I'll demonstrate with the "iris" dataset, but first, I'll also create an "iris_2" dataset that has one `NA` value.

```
iris_2 <- iris
iris_2$Sepal.Length[10] <- NA
```

Let's compare the aggregation output, which in these cases will just be the second column. You'll see that the "iris" dataset, which has no missing values, returns a rectangular matrix as the second "column" in your `data.frame`. Because of our one `NA` value, the "iris_2" dataset, however, gets stored as a `list`, which is what *you* want for your particular purpose.

```
(irisagg <- aggregate(iris["Sepal.Length"], iris["Species"], summary))[[2]]
#      Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
# [1,]  4.3   4.800    5.0 5.006     5.2  5.8
# [2,]  4.9   5.600    5.9 5.936     6.3  7.0
# [3,]  4.9   6.225    6.5 6.588     6.9  7.9
(iris_2agg <- aggregate(iris_2["Sepal.Length"], iris_2["Species"], summary))[[2]]
# $`0`
#     Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
#    4.300   4.800   5.000   5.008   5.200   5.800       1 
# 
# $`1`
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   4.900   5.600   5.900   5.936   6.300   7.000 
# 
# $`2`
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   4.900   6.225   6.500   6.588   6.900   7.900
```

Here's how we would put it back into a list.

```
irisagg$Summary <- unlist(apply(irisagg[[2]], 1, list), recursive = FALSE)
irisagg$Summary
# [[1]]
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   4.300   4.800   5.000   5.006   5.200   5.800 
# 
# [[2]]
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   4.900   5.600   5.900   5.936   6.300   7.000 
# 
# [[3]]
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   4.900   6.225   6.500   6.588   6.900   7.900
```

Of course, a much more direct approach would be to make use of the `simplify` argument for `aggregate` and do:

```
(iris_3agg <- aggregate(iris["Sepal.Length"], 
                        iris["Species"], summary, 
                        simplify = FALSE))[[2]]
# $`0`
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   4.300   4.800   5.000   5.006   5.200   5.800 
# 
# $`1`
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   4.900   5.600   5.900   5.936   6.300   7.000 
# 
# $`2`
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   4.900   6.225   6.500   6.588   6.900   7.900
```

Applying it to your example, "sprdiurnal" is the subset that's giving you trouble. View `sprdiurnal$ws` by itself and verify that it's a matrix. Let's convert it to a list.

```
sprdiurnal$ws2 <- unlist(apply(sprdiurnal$ws, 1, list), recursive=FALSE)
```

Now you can proceed with `boxplot` as you were doing with the other seasons.

```
boxplot(sprdiurnal$ws2, e..t..c...)
```

Or, remake your `sprdiurnal` object using:

```
sprdiurnal <- aggregate(spr9["ws"], 
                        format(spr9["date"],"%H"), 
                        summary, na.rm = TRUE, 
                        simplify = FALSE)
```

And proceed as before.